# Logarithmically  spacing number

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, logging, mathematica-8

I would like to test several values of intensity.

I need them to be spaced logarithmically from 1 to 1000. Yet I just use 1, 10, 100, 1000, but I would like to have more data point, let`s say 10.

**How could I find 10 logarithmically spaced number between 1 and 1000 in Mathematica ?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If `a` is start, `c` is end and `b` is number of intervals:

```
{a, b, c} = {1, 10, 1000};
t = (c/a)^(1/b) // N
a*t^Range[b]

1.99526
{1.99526, 3.98107, 7.94328, 15.8489, 31.6228, 63.0957, 125.893, 251.189, 501.187, 1000.}
```

I used `N` just to see better, what do we have.

Comment: I was going to post something very similar but you beat me to it by 2 seconds. By the way, `Power` is `Listable` so you could simply do `a*t^Range[b]`.

Comment: @Heike, nice! Updated. I spotted this question from RSS 30 minutes after it was published. It's my 1st Mathematica answer, so I tried to be fast ..P

Comment: @Nakilon You could use `Range[0,b]` as Leonid did to get full list starting from `a`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way:

```
In[11]:= base = Block[{a}, a /. NSolve[a^9 == 1000, a][[-1, 1]]]
Out[11]= 2.15443

In[13]:= base^Range[0, 9]
Out[13]= {1., 2.15443, 4.64159, 10., 21.5443, 46.4159, 100., 
  215.443,464.159, 1000.}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a much shorter and more direct way to get the same:

```
In[18]:= N[10^Range[0, 3, 1/3]]

Out[18]= {1., 2.15443, 4.64159, 10., 21.5443, 46.4159, 100., 
215.443, 464.159, 1000.}
```

Comment: Thank you Leonid, would you mind explaining the use of "Block", "/." & the curious "[[-1,1]]". It works, but I can`t get a grasp at that syntax yet.

Comment: @500 I think it is much clearer just to use `NSolve[a^9==1000,a,Reals]`. Instead of `Block` one can use [Formal Symbol](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) [`\[FormalA]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/FormalA.html) with the same success: `base=\[FormalA]/.NSolve[\[FormalA]^9==1000,\[FormalA],Reals]//First`. "`/.`" is just [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html).

Comment: @500 I think, it is much easier to just use `base = N[Power[1000, 1/9]]`. Actually, `base` is a cubic root of `10`. Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Thank You ! I was actually looking into that. But could not find out how to get the nth roots. You answered that question to : Power & fraction !

Answer (score 4):

Solve the equation `x ** 9 = 1000` -- then your numbers are:  `x ** 0`, `x ** 1`, ... `x ** 9`.

note:  where `x ** y` means `x` to the power of `y`