# Deriving formula on how to logarithmically distribute numbers in a range?

Tags: math

I needed to logarithmically distribute a number in a range of 2-200 in a determined number of intervals. The formula used in [another question worked perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7778510/8581714); I just couldn't explain how or why it works.

Can anyone explain how this function works? Perhaps derive it for me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking some math questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's projecting evenly-spaced intervals to logarithmicly-spaced intervals by raising some number `X` to each interval.

The example distributes the range 1-1000 into 10 intervals.  The end result is that some number X to the 10th power will be 1,000 (`X^10 = 1,000`).  So X is `1,000 ^ (1.10)` = `1.99526`

Now the range

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

is projected to a logarithmic range using the function

```
f(x) = 1.99536 ^ x
```

which results in

```
1.99526, 3.98107, 7.94328, 15.8489, 31.6228, 63.0957, 125.893, 251.189, 501.187, 1000
```